# Uncaught TypeError: TodoActions.createTodo is not a function at Todos.createTodo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I have an error as posted in title. I've tried to put some code into flux pattern so I have:

1. TodoActions file which represents actions
2. Todos file which represents view
3. I have also Dispatcher file and Store file, but i think the problem doesn't touch 
   them.

While clicking the button in Todos.js it calls the createTodo() function from Todos.js and while executing

- TodoActions.createTodo('x');

An error occurs ->  TodoActions.createTodo is not a function at Todos.createTodo

Todos.js

```
import React from "react";
import Todo from "../components/Todo";
import TodoStore from "../stores/TodoStore";
import * as TodoActions from "../actions/TodoActions";

export default class Todos extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    TodoStore.on("change", () =>{
      this.setState({
        todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
      });
    });
  }

  createTodo(){
    TodoActions.createTodo('x');
  }

render() {
    const { todos } = this.state;
const TodoComponents = todos.map((todo) => {
    return <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo}/>;
});

return (
  <div>
  <button onClick={this.createTodo.bind(this)}>Create!</button>
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <ul>{TodoComponents}</ul>
  </div>
);
  }
}
```

TodoActions.js

```
import dispatcher from "../thedispatcher/dispatcher";

export function createTodo(text){
    dispatcher.dispatch({
        type: "CREATE_TODO",
        text,
    });
}
```

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkscs.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try  using `createTodo = () => {
    TodoActions.createTodo('x');
  }`

Comment: Can you share the project's file structure so the bad import path can be ruled out ?

Comment: cdaiga -> unfortunatelly it doesn't help

Comment: just import it like import {createTodo} from '../actions/'; and use it like createTodo() ,etc.

Comment: Mayank Singh -> error is still present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the file **TodoActions** is bing imported instead of **TodoActions.js**, so remove it if you don't need it or rename it so the **TodoActions.js** 'll be imported.

Comment: Sure! I haven't even realized that i have such a file. Thanks a lot mate!